# Error JSON.parse with JQuery Autocomplete ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when I try to use the plugin Jquery Autocomplete. I am use ASP.Net C# and SQL for the BD.

The error is the follow:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

I read into forums and say that it's for an invalid JSON format but I don't know how fix it or if it is the error.

My Model:

```
public class ListasAutocompletarModel
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public JsonResult mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo(string Codigo)
    {
        List<ListasAutocompletarModel> list = new List<ListasAutocompletarModel>();
        try
        {
            DataTable datos = DM.mostrar_Lista_Codigo(Codigo);
            foreach (DataRow data in datos.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new ListasAutocompletarModel
                {
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(data["ID"]),
                    label = data["Codigo"].ToString(),
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Classes.ErrorLogger.Registrar(this, e.ToString());
        }
        return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And my js:

```
$('#txtDatosMaestros_Codigo').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DatosMaestros/mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { Codigo: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.label, value: item.value };
                }))
            }
        });
    },
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Open your Network tool in the brower's Developer Tool.  Then run your autocomplete to trigger the AJAX. Now click on the call to `mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo`. Look in the Response tab. What do you see? I'm guessing that what's there is not valid JSON.

Comment: is the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` creating an issue since its a POST request? also, it looks like youre returning a list but from what I can see the Ajax isnt setup for that type of return?

Comment: @AndrewE that only _allows_ it to be a GET, it doesn't _force_ it. But not having a `[HttpPost]` attribute on the action method might be a factor, potentially. We need OP to give us some actual debugging / error info, as I've requested in my first comment. Then we can narrow down the problem. And "the Ajax isnt setup for that type of return"...what makes you say that? the `data` is passed to $.map which (as per the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)) accepts an array as the first parameter. So I'd say it's ideally set up to receive a list / array.

Comment: That’s cool, I didn’t know about the $.map, you learn something new each day

Comment: @ADyson The call appear as `DatosMaestros?query=Test` and show the HTML structure [screenshot](https://imgbbb.com/images/2020/02/06/Error.png)

Comment: `DatosMaestros?query=Test` is not the same URL as in your code above. Also that is doing a `GET`, but your AJAX runs a `POST`. Are you sure you're looking at the right request? According to your code, you should be seeing a `POST` request going to `/DatosMaestros/mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo`

Comment: Yeah, It´s the request but it show me that, If I put the resquest `/DatosMaestros/mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo?Codigo=x` in effect return an array [capture](https://imgbbb.com/images/2020/02/06/Capture.png)

Comment: Ok. So `mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo` works if you access it direct in a browser via a GET request. That's good. But my point is that what you showed from your Network tab is a totally different URL, so that's irrelevant as far as I can see. You need to capture the moment that your autocomplete triggers an AJAX POST request to `mostrarListaDatosMaestrosCodigo`, as per the code in your question. That is what we are investigating.